# Ruby: How to use database.yml with multiple users and multiple databases per environment

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Scenario:

- You have read access to one or more databases, which you don't own
- You have write access to your own local database, but you'll be using an application account

The way I have been doing this is to create a file similar to `database.yml` (some sort of switch statement) and create different connections manually (eg using `require 'pg'`), rather than having rails automatically do it .

Is there a way to configure database.yml to have these various setups per environment and have ruby/rails either create all connections, or know which I want based on a parameter?

```
development:
    adapter: postgresql
    host: localhost
    port: 5432
    username: application_id
    password: 
    database: foo

development:
    adapter: postgresql
    host: 111.111.111.111
    port: 5432
    username: user_id
    password: somepass
    database: bar

development:
    adapter: postgresql
    host: 222.222.222.222
    port: 5432
    username: user_id
    password: somepass
    database: foobar
```

Comment: You probably need a [multi-tenant add-on for Rails](https://www.ruby-toolbox.com/categories/Multitenancy) to make this easier.

Comment: @tadman oo something to look at, I've been taking some suggestions and morphing the ActiveRecord base class -- actually after looking multitenant-pg, it seems to be doing the same thing, but using schemas, which I'm not sure is desired.  I'll have to look into that further -- thanks